# How to disable modified time-stamp in windows?

Tags: windows-7, privacy, timestamp

Disabling `Accessed` time-stamp of files/folders in Windows is pretty easy. However, when you save a file, Windows updates its `Modified` time-stamp, and along with that the `Accessed` time-stamp also gets updated. So how can I prevent Windows from updating `Modified` time-stamps?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686007/how-do-i-change-the-modified-timestamp-of-a-file-in-windows-using-a-batch-file

http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/easily-change-file-folder-created-accessed-modified-timestamps/

these are the links that might be useful

SKTimeStamp is great tool, I have used it, works fine.

> The program works by adding a “TimeStamps” tab to the standard Explorer file properties 
>   dialog, which makes it very easy to use. Just select the files you’d like to modify,  right-click one, choose Properties > TimeStamps and set the Created, Last Modified or Last  Accessed times to whatever you want.
>
> Or alternatively, check the timestamps you’d like to modify and click Touch to update them to the current time.
>
> You do have to be a little careful here, at SKTimeStamp doesn’t restrict what you can do. If you’d like to set a file to look as though it was created after it was last modified, say, then you can do exactly that. But while Windows doesn’t care, you may find that kind of contradiction causes problems with applications that use logic based on file timestamps (backup tools, say).

[Link to review](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/easily-change-file-folder-created-accessed-modified-timestamps/)